# Concurrent access to a QTcpSocket object

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtcpsocket

I created a class that inherits from `QThread` in order to have a thread running with a `QTcpSocket` object. When this thread starts, it connects to a server: if the connection is refused or if the connection is lost, the thread tries to reconnect to the server, trying to reconnect for an indefinite number of times. In other words, this thread tries to keep the connection with the specified server.

A `QTcpSocket*` is declared as the attribute member `_socket` of my class. The first line of the `run()` function instantiates the `_socket` object and tries to connect to the server. The last line of the `run()` function calls `_socket->disconnectFromHost()`. I registered the event disconnected of the `_socket` object, in order to call `_socket->deleteLater()`.

This thread that I created is working properly.
Now I would add a function in order to send data to the server: this function should call the `write()` function of the `_socket` object and it should be invoked by another thread. So, should I use a mutex in order to use the `_socket` object?

Answer (score 1):

> *a class that inherits from QThread*

Begin by addressing this first. Many people here will tell you that [You're Doing it Wrong!](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/)

QThread, is more of a thread controller than a thread, so unless you want to change how Qt is going to manage threads, I recommend that you don't inherit from it. Instead, follow the method as described in [How to Really, Truly Use QThread](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).

I'm going to assume that you've a good reason to use the QTCpSocket in a separate thread, even though it's asynchronous.

If you have a QTcpSocket on a different thread and want to call the socket's write function, you should be using the signal / slot mechanism, rather than calling the object's function directly from a different thread.

So, to summarise, following reading the [excellent article](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) of how to use QThread,  refactor your code to create a separate object, derived from QObject, which can be moved to a new thread. Then use the signal / slot mechanism to send data to that object, which can then call the socket's write function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to send and receive signals from the main thread to your worker thread. The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html) explains pretty good how to do this:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void doWork(const QString &parameter) {
        QString result;
        /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */
        emit resultReady(result);
    }

signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &result);
};

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
        workerThread.start();
    }
    ~Controller() {
        workerThread.quit();
        workerThread.wait();
    }
public slots:
    void handleResults(const QString &);
signals:
    void operate(const QString &);
};
```

You must create a `QObject` that will have a member function doing the operations you want to have in your separate thread. You [move](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) this `QObject` to the `QThread` you want to execute the operation in changing its [affinity](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity) and send/receive signals to/from it.

In cases like these it is not necessary and not recommended to inherit `QThread`. But if you do so, don't forget to call `exec()` in the `run()` member function so that the thread starts its own event loop(so that it can handle asynchronous operations).

So no, you don't need mutexes for your operations. The event loops of the main thread and worker thread can beautifully communicate, send signals to each other and synchronize.

I recommend looking at this [Consume/Producer](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2006/12/04/threading-without-the-headache/) solution which synchronizes 2 threads and which was created by `Bradley Hughes` back in 2006 when `QThread::run()` wasn't starting the event loop by default. Here is an updated version of his example:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <stdio.h>

enum {
    Limit = 123456,
    BlockSize = 7890
};

class Producer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QByteArray data;
    int bytes;

public:
    inline Producer() : bytes(0) { }

public slots:
    void produce()
    {
        int remaining = Limit - bytes;
        if (remaining == 0) {
            emit finished();
            return;
        }

        // this will never happen
        if (data.size() != 0)
            qFatal("Producer: Consumer failed to consume!");

        int size = qMin(int(BlockSize), remaining);
        bytes += size;
        remaining -= size;
        data.fill('Q', size);

        printf("Producer: produced %d more bytes, %d of %d total\n", size, bytes, Limit);
        emit produced(&data);
    }

signals:
    void produced(QByteArray *data);
    void finished();
};

class Consumer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int bytes;

public:
    inline Consumer() : bytes(0) { }

public slots:
    void consume(QByteArray *data)
    {
        // this will never happen
        if (data->size() == 0)
            qFatal("Consumer: Producer failed to produce!");

        int remaining = Limit - bytes;
        int size = data->size();
        remaining -= size;
        bytes += size;
        data->clear();

        printf("Consumer: consumed %d more bytes, %d of %d total\n", size, bytes, Limit);
        emit consumed();
        if (remaining == 0)
            emit finished();
    }

signals:
    void consumed();
    void finished();
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    // create the producer and consumer and plug them together
    Producer producer;
    Consumer consumer;
    producer.connect(&consumer,
                     SIGNAL(consumed()),
                     SLOT(produce()));
    consumer.connect(&producer,
                     SIGNAL(produced(QByteArray *)),
                     SLOT(consume(QByteArray *)));

    // they both get their own thread
    QThread producerThread;
    producer.moveToThread(&producerThread);
    QThread consumerThread;
    consumer.moveToThread(&consumerThread);

    // start producing once the producer's thread has started
    producer.connect(&producerThread,
                     SIGNAL(started()),
                     SLOT(produce()));

    // when the consumer is done, it stops its thread
    consumerThread.connect(&consumer,
                           SIGNAL(finished()),
                           SLOT(quit()));
    // when consumerThread is done, it stops the producerThread
    producerThread.connect(&consumerThread,
                           SIGNAL(finished()),
                           SLOT(quit()));
    // when producerThread is done, it quits the application
    app.connect(&producerThread,
                SIGNAL(finished()),
                SLOT(quit()));

    // go!
    producerThread.start();
    consumerThread.start();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Read [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/thread-basics.html) for more info.